# Redirect User Depending on Language

Tags: php, redirect

I have the following code:

```
<?php
// List of available localized versions as 'lang code' => 'url' map
$sites = array(
    "da" => "http://www.mysite.com/",
);

// Get 2 char lang code
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

// Set default language if a `$lang` version of site is not available
if (!in_array($lang, array_keys($sites)))
    $lang = 'en';

// Finally redirect to desired location
header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]);
?>
```

This will redirect the user to the Danish (da) version of the site, which is the main site, if it's a Danish website client. This is excellent.

But, I want, if the user isn't Danish, but Polish, German, etc. it redirects them to the English version of the site, which is located at the subdomain

```
http://en.mysite.com/
```

How do I implement that into the existing code? Thanks in advance!
- Frederick Andersen

**EDIT**

A solution like;

```
$sites = array(
    "da" => "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "en" => "http://en.mysite.com/"
);
```

Doesn't work since it creates a loop error when redirecting - at least in Google Chrome.

**EDIT 2**

```
session_start();
if (isset( $_SESSION['redirect']))
{
   // do nothing / continue with rest of page
}
else
{
   $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;

// List of available localized versions as 'lang code' => 'url' map
$sites = array(
    "da" => "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "en" => "http://en.mysite.com/"
);

// Get 2 char lang code
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

// Set default language if a `$lang` version of site is not available
if (!in_array($lang, array_keys($sites)))
    $lang = 'en';

// Finally redirect to desired location
header('Location: ' . $sites[$lang]);

   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add the default option to your array:

```
$sites = array(
    "da" => "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "en" => "http://en.mysite.com/"
);
```

**Edit:** If you are calling this same code in `"http://en.mysite.com/"` again, it will create a loop. The obvious solution would be to not call this code there, but an alternative solution would be to set a session variable to indicate that the language selection has already taken place.

To add that session variable you could do something like:

```
session_start();
if (isset( $_SESSION['redirect']))
{
   // do nothing / continue with rest of page
}
else
{
   $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
   // your language selection code with header call
   exit();
}
```

Comment: But by doing so, it will create a loop when redirecting and display an error - atleast in Chrome. Thanks for the quick answer, though!

Comment: @Frederick Andersen If it does not create a loop in the Danish version, it should not do that in the English version either unless you are doing something different there as compared to the Danish version.

Comment: How would you go around creating a session variable? And en.mysite.com is not redirecting anywhere.

Comment: @Frederick Andersen I have added a small example where your code fits in the last section.

Comment: I would put all the code I have posted in the main post between the $_SESSION['redirect'] = true; and exit(); right?

Comment: @Frederick Andersen Yes, but you really should try to avoid calling that code at all as this is just patching things up that should not happen in the first place.

Comment: I have updated the main post with EDIT 2 - is that how I supposedly should write the code in the top of my header.php? If so, it doesn't work, or I'm more likely doing something wrong, since it just skips that code and goes directly to the main site.

- How would I "avoid calling that code at all (..)"

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Frederick Andersen Just make sure that code does not get called when you enter `http://en.mysite.com/`.

Comment: There is nothing at `http://en.mysite.com/`: only a `index.php` document, where it says: "This is the English version". But there still is a problem. It doesn't redirect now - at all - when using the code in **EDIT 2**.

Comment: @Frederick Andersen If there is nothing in `http://en.mysite.com/` your original code is not creating the loop and the session stuff is not necessary, just the change to the array.

Comment: When I remove the `session_start();` from the code, it works flawlessly, and when `session_start();` **IS** there it doesn't redirect. **BUT** when the code is asked to redirect to the danish version, where the redirect code is, when `session_start();` is removed, it generates the loop error. What should the code then be?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sites = array(
    "da" => "http://www.mysite.com/",
    "en" => "http://en.mysite.com/"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

    $sub_domain = ($lang == "da") ? "www" : "en";

    $link = "http://".$sub_domain.".mysite.com/";

    header('Location: ' . $link);
```