# PHP Redirect if language parameter is not in URL

Tags: php, url, localization

I have a url such as: `http://localhost/project` and when the user goes there, I want to redirect to `http://localhost/project/en`. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: the efficient way would be to use a `.htaccess` file and declare a redirect rule in it.

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 maybe "en" is an example, he might like to redirect user getting his browser's favorite languages

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect User Depending on Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453152/redirect-user-depending-on-language)

Comment: It depends on what exactly are you trying to do. If I guess that you want to support multiple languages, then perhaps it is not a good way to handle it. Language selection should not be a part of URL. Use Content-negotiation, sessions, cookies to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. You should be using virtual hosts and rewrite uri to prepare your URL properly, but if you don't want to bother with those and want a method that "just works" exactly for the problem you presented, then try this:

```
$explode = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (count($explode) == 1)){
   header('Location: http://localhost/project/en');
}
```

**Edit after comments**

Try this, but beware that I haven't tested it, as I don't have my prod. environment here, but it should work. If not, comment :)

```
$explode = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$endsWithSlash = FALSE;
end($explode);
if (empty($explode[key($explode)])){
   unset($explode[key($explode)]);
   $endsWithSlash = TRUE;
}
if (end($explode) != 'en'){
   $url = 'http://localhost';
   $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if (!$endsWithSlash){ $url .= '/'; }
   $url .= 'en';
   header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

Comment: I like this one the best. My only concern is I need to implement it assuming I could be in a directory such as `http://localhost/dir1/dir2/en`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this programmatically or using something at the web server level (e.g. mod_rewrite with Apache). Since you've mentioned PHP explicitly, I'll provide you the following.

In a folder called 'project' at your document root, create an index.php with the following:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://localhost/project/en" );
exit(0);
?>
```

Here's a link that shows this style and other methods (including mod_rewrite) to handle this:

http://www.phatz.com/301redirect.php